# FlowLayoutPanel not showing all contents?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Very weird situation going on with a FlowLayoutPanel...

I have been dynamically adding user controls to my panel.  This user control has a height of 105.  If I have my FlowLayoutPanelwidth to only show 1 "column" of controls, it will only display 296 of them.  The rest of the controls are grayed out at the bottom of the flowlayoutpanel.  If I widen the flp to allow 2 "columns" of controls, I can see 592 of them, with the remainder grayed out at the bottom.  I have gone in and resized the user control to make it shorter in height, which works in some respects (i.e. it works when I have two columns, but not just 1), and can go forward with this work-around.

So, I guess my question is, why does the FlowLayoutPanel behave in this fashion?  It seems (based on what I saw) that there is a limit to how much data the FLP will show at one time.

Comment: That's a lot of controls to put into any panel. Have you considered using a data grid instead?

Comment: @Paul. I have, but the stakeholder has not :P. Besides, final product will probably not display half that amount at one time; I was just testing to see how it worked.  However, I have just discovered that I can get the panel to display by calling PerformLayout in the Scroll event of the Panel. Not sure why the FLP behaves in this way.

Comment: I just recalled that Suspend/ResumeLayout functions are often times necessary in these kinds of situations. See my answer below.

Comment: When you have *that* many controls it becomes really important to religiously use the Dispose() method or the Using statement.  Painting artifacts like that usually indicate your app has consumed its quota of GDI handles.

Comment: @Hans, I understand the use of Dispose, and use it.  I am also aware of the issue with handles, but this seems to be something else.  It just won't seem to paint below a certain point within the panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comment just reminded me that when you're adding many controls to any container it is a good idea to do this:

```
YourPanel.SuspendLayout();

// populate panel with controls

YourPanel.ResumeLayout(false);
```

This in effect stops the container (panel) from re-rendering itself every time you add a control until you're done adding controls. In the very least your panel creation will be smoother and faster. Not sure if this might fix your issue or avoid the need for a hack with PerformLayout.

If you look at your Form's designer file you will actually see this in action in the InitializeComponent function.

Comment: Thanks, I already use SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout. It does indeed make the panel creation smoother and faster, but it does not prevent this oddity from occurring. I think I just need to go back to the stakeholder and push for a more simplistic approach.

Comment: @APrough: Another idea: Years ago I had to implement a panel with dozens of buttons. The behavior and performance was atrocious and the better solution was to actually owner draw a custom control that simulated buttons, focus, clicks etc. I'm not sure how complex your controls are (buttons are relatively simple) but owner drawn can be the way to go.

Comment: I might have to go with some sort of owner drawn control.  My current solution works, but I do not like the way it is being handled.  At this point, you have the solution.  If I find any better method, I will post back.